# An infinitely generated Lie algebra, its finitely generated envelope

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

If a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ is finitely generated, its enveloing algebra $U\mathfrak g$ is finitely generated as an associative algebra. In fact, taking the enveloping algebra of the surjection $\mathrm{FreeLie}(x_1,\dotsc x_n)\twoheadrightarrow \mathfrak g$ gives what we want. My question is:

Does the converse hold? Equivalently, is there an infinitely generated $\mathfrak g$ with finitely generated $U\mathfrak g$?

I couldn't come up with counterexamples. Thank you.